# Arduino serial informations

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sketch

Is it possible to change serial information of arduinos board ? 
For example I have an arduino uno with this serial informations :

```
{ 
      comName: '/dev/cu.usbmodem1411',
      manufacturer: 'Arduino (www.arduino.cc)',
      serialNumber: '75430333137351804230',
      pnpId: '',
      locationId: '0x14100000',
      vendorId: '0x2341',
      productId: '0x0043' 
}
```

I want to modify for example the manufacturer to be able to automatically detect the device whatever the comName is. I don't want to detect arduino board I want to detect arduino board modify by me without make a serial connection.

Comment: Have you purchased a vendor ID yet?

Comment: No didn't know that was possible... Where I can buy one ? How to use it after that ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have [purchased a USB vendor ID](http://www.usb.org/developers/vendor/) you can edit the firmware within the Arduino installation at `hardware/arduino/firmwares/atmegaxxu2/arduino-usbserial/` with your vendor ID, chosen product ID, and other USB parameters as you wish and then rebuild the firmware and upload it to the ATmega16U2 on the board via ISP.

If you do not wish to purchase a vendor ID for the time being then you can use 0x6666, the prototype vendor ID, in the meantime, but you are not allowed to make products using that vendor ID available to the public.